# Jenkins-ios: how to launch the iphone simulator from Jenkins

Tags: ios, jenkins

I'm using the `Jenkins CI` as build management tool on the build server and I am running my unit test cases using the below command through `Jenkins`.

```
export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator -project MyStore2.xcodeproj -scheme MyStore2 -configuration Debug RUN_APPLICATION_TESTS_WITH_IOS_SIM=YES ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO clean test 2>&1 | /usr/local/bin/ocunit2junit
```

The iPhone simulator is not launched from the `Jenkins UI`, whereas if I use the same command in command prompt, it is working fine.

The build console output is as below:

```
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/iOSUnitTestCaseSample/MyStore2/Images.xcassets
2014-08-12 03:11:38.979 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[92947:303] CFPreferences: user home directory at file:///Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/User/ is unavailable. User domains will be volatile.
/* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyStore2-cfjvjlzuxlhdpddpszyhlozlqjdw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyStore2.app/LaunchImage-700-568h@2x.png
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyStore2-cfjvjlzuxlhdpddpszyhlozlqjdw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyStore2.app/Assets.car
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyStore2-cfjvjlzuxlhdpddpszyhlozlqjdw/Build/Intermediates/MyStore2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyStore2.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist

.
.
.

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyStore2-cfjvjlzuxlhdpddpszyhlozlqjdw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyStore2Tests.xctest/MyStore2Tests -o /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyStore2-cfjvjlzuxlhdpddpszyhlozlqjdw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyStore2Tests.xctest.dSYM
```

Please guide me on how to resolve this issue. Help Appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved this in the past by using the JNLP client on the Jenkins slave and having a user logged in.  My theory is that if you launch the slave agent via SSH, there is no windowing environment for the simulator to run in.

Another solution is to use [ios-sim](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim).

Comment: It was issue related to the permission, the Jenkins users is running as a guest user which doesn't have permission to access the system resources (simulator), not I have installed the Jenkins under admin user and it is working fine.

Comment: OMG, this solves my problems. I couldn't run the tests (unit/integration) with Jenkins due to I had the slave configured to be connected with SSH. Connecting with JNLP solves it. Thank you!!